# Opencart custom database lookup and display

Tags: php, opencart

Currently, trying to get this to work with Opencart, but I think my knowledge of the file structure needs some help.

I have added an additional field into the DB for Opencart, which I added to provide data based on the person logging in with an affiliate code.

After I query that file, I would like the fields echo'ed in the header.tpl output to the screen for every page.

If I query the database in the Index.php file, for the tracking number in the DB, it returns the right information the first time and displays it in the header, but then when I click on the products, the next screen there will be an error, because it looks like the Index.php file is constantly being re-run for every page on Opencart, even when the URL link changes ? Is there another file I am missing which I should put the query into, and also where do I place variables to display on each header file.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Be very careful about adding fields to the DB.  One day there may be an update that will wipe out all your work, your data and likely your entire site.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to know what exactly you are wanting to do based on your question. If you are wanting to display affiliate data in the header, you should be using the file `/catalog/controller/common/header.php` to assign the data to the header view. You should then be adding the data in the `/catalog/view/theme/your-theme-name/template/common/header.tpl` file.

Really speaking, you should be using

```
if($this->affiliate->isLogged()) {
    // Code here
}
```

To make sure that the affiliate is actually logged in before showing the data. To pull the data from the database, you are probably going to want to edit `/system/library/affiliate.php` and pull the data that way rather than in a controller file, so you can get any of the information across the store files

Comment: Thanks for the reply. It's for the customer logging in from the affiliates link, not the other way around. I am looking up the affiliates information from the db and listing the name or other data in the header based on the link. You mentioned to query the DB in the common header.php file, so I will give that a try!

Comment: Still having the same problem if I put the code in the header.php common file. Is there a isLogged() in variable for a customer logged into an affiliates account ? That would make this simple!  Also, is there a way in PHP to only query the database once, its trying to query it again after i click on a product from the main page. I get this message  Undefined index: tracking in catalog/controller/common/header.php

Comment: If you want to save a value, you should use sessions to do so. Affiliates and customers are not related, which is why I'm having a hard time understanding what it is you want to do to be honest

Comment: Also, you can use an isLogged for a customer at any point

if($this->customer->isLogged() && $this->affiliate->isLogged()) {
    ...
}